# .htaccess - make urls like page:part

Tags: .htaccess

I have a .htaccess that sends these urls:

```
http://example.com/this/is/test/
```

to index.php that gets the url like this:

```
index.php?var1=this&var2=is&var3=test
```

All I want to do is change the `/` to `:`means the url will be like this:

```
http://example.com/this:is:test
```

that sends the variables to index page just like before. Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?([^/]+)?/?   [NC]
RewriteRule .*     index.php?var1=%1&var2=%2&var3=%3   [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `%{REQUEST_URI}` to match parts. So, in order to make what you want you have to change your `/` to `:`. I'll also use a better syntax.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/([^:]+):([^:]+):([^/]+)/? index.php?var1=$1&var2=$2&var3=$3 [L]
```